# AXIOS error: getting connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:80 with express/typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, axios

I am getting an error with axios. The error is ""message": "connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:80","

I am typeScript and express. Can you please let me know to how to resolve this issue

**Route.ts**

```
 export class UsersRoutes extends CommonRoutesConfig {
    constructor(app: express.Application) {
        super(app, 'userRoutes');
    }
    configureRoutes() {
        this.app.route(`/v2/candidate/`).post(UsersController.getCandidate);
    }
}
```

**COnTRoller.ts**

```
async getCandidate(req: express.Request, res: express.Response, next: express.NextFunction) {
        try {
            const result = await usersService.getCandidate(req.body);
            res.status(200).json(result);
        } catch (err) {
            next(new HttpException(err.response.status, err.response.data));
        }
    }
```

**SERVICE.TS**

**The URL is not localhost . It is something like "https://myapi.com"**

```
 async getCandidate(body: any) {
        const url = util.format(process.env.GET_CANDIDATE);
        const token = await gjwt.getToken();
        axios.defaults.headers.common = { Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` };
        try {
          
            const res = await axios.post(url, body);
            return res.data;
        } catch (err) {
            throw err;
        }
    }
```

**MY http call**

```
POST http://localhost:3000/v2/candidate
 Content-Type: application/json

{
  "accessToken":"mytoken"
}
```

Comment: could you get data from curl or postman ?

Comment: no.  This is the response from POSTMAN 
"message": "connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:80",
    "name": "Error",
    "stack": "Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:80\n    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1142:16)",
    "config": {
        "url": "\"https://mydomail.com/api/candidate/v2/mobileSignIn/\";",
        "method": "post",

Comment: Are you browsing accessing direct URL? I got similar issue on Nuxt.js, when some pages are called directly on development enviroment, axios ignore the setup from nuxt.config.js and use the defaults: URI + Port 80. If I browse the app using menus from application works fine. In production since the ports are default (80 and 443) this error does not occours. Solution for development components in my situation is use hard coded URL (http://localhost:3000/v2/candidate/), and before delivery it to production change those for /post /users /candidate etc...